# Managing large log files

Tags: php, debugging, logging

We have a crawler that persistently crawls our target sites, it's log files are turning out to be quite huge. Over 1 GB in some cases, I'm not too comfortable with deleting or overwriting them. Any examples of how you managed large log files?

Comment: Define "manage": read, tail, archive, compress, log less, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a cron script to rotate the log files on a daily basis. Basically, you rename your `logfile.log` to `logfile-YYYY-MM-DD.log`. This way, instead of one huge logfile, you have smaller ones and are able to find logged messages from a certain time period easily. If you also compress your rotated logs, you will save even more disk space.

Comment: check out log rotate docs: http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html. it's a standard tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use log4net, log4j, or other logging frameworks that automatically change the file names based on file size or date. http://logging.apache.org/log4net/